# Solving Trigonometric Equations $\cos{2x}=\cos{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you solve $\cos{2x}=\cos{x}$?

I'm really stuck, I know the first step is to isolate the variables, but after that I don't know what to do.

Comment: **Hint:** $$ \cos(2x) = \cos ^2(x)-\sin ^2(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

$2\cos^2x-1=\cos x$. This is two degree equation. So

$$(2\cos x+1)(\cos x-1)=0$$

$$\cos x=1,-\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$$x=2nπ,\dfrac{2π}3+2nπ,\dfrac{4π}3+2nπ$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\implies2x =2n\pi\pm x$$ where $n$ is any integer

See also: [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) and $\sin y=0\implies y=m\pi$